# How to use fortran to the type of real plus characters

Tags: fortran

```
program WaterPressure
implicit none

real :: E, t
real, parameter :: E0 = 6.11

! ==========main====================
E = E0 * 10**(7.5 * t/(237.3 + t))

write(*,*)'请输入输入t 的值:'
read(*,*)t 
print*, 'When t=' + character(t)'I want to print' + character(E)

end
```

how because `t` and  `E`  , are real not character , so it will show error , how can I to realize what I want.

Comment: You don't need to convert reals (or integers, or whatever) to strings before printing them, just print them directly. Note also that the string concatenation operator in Fortran is `//`, not `+`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the asterisk for formatting, you can just add additional variables to be printed with comma, like this:

```
program WaterPressure
    implicit none
    real :: t, E
    real, parameter :: E0 = 6.11

    print *, "Please enter t:"
    read *, t

    E = E0 * 10**(7.5 * t/(237.3 + t))

    print *, 't=', t, ' -> E=', E
end program WaterPressure
```

This will automatically convert everything to printable characters, but if you need more control, you need to look into format statements.